# How to set the same total length of y-axis ticks digits

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently my y-axis ticks all have the same number of digits after the decimal point, so the total length of the ticks is different. I want the total lengths of tick-digits to be the same. How can I do this?

My code is as follows:

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%1.3f'))
```

Here the y-axis ticks have different total lengths:

[image]

I want the total lengths of tick-digits to be the same:

[image: y-axis ticks has the same lengths]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FuncFormatter() instead.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import math
```

Create a function outputting the desired label:

```
def my_format(val, pos):

    n = 3
    y = abs(val)

    dec = max(0,
              min(n,n-int(math.log10(y)))) if y else n

    return f"{val:.{dec}f}"
```

*(dec adapted from the accepted answer in [Format float with fixed amount of digits python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863996/format-float-with-fixed-amount-of-digits-python))

Apply the function to your axis, instead of the FormatStrFormatter():

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(my_format))
```

Comment: Note that the two argument formulation of my_format() is required by FuncFormatter(), even though we only use the first one.